# How do you check Shiny App is successfully deployed?

Tags: r, shiny

We have an app, hosted on *shinyapps.io*, that is updated and deployed daily - at an unsociable hour - using a batchfile script.

I know one can test the app locally (like in RStudio) or looking at the logs using:

`shinyapps::showLogs(account = "MYACCOUNT", appName = "myapp")`

But is there a way to **trigger a warning** if the app is not successfully deployed. For example, send an email alert if the deployment fails.

*How do others check whether their shiny apps are up and running happy?*

Comment: You can get application status using `data.frame(lapply(shinyapps::applications(account='someUser'), unlist))`, but if you deploy application using script then it is a good place to check for deployment errors. Finally you can use some automation software (like selenium) to access site after deployment and check if it responds correctly.